# how to stock and parse the "response.data" in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, axios

i try to do a script that parse all "id" of the "response.data" in js.

Here is my code:

```
var axios = require('axios');

async function get_all_id() {

let config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://.../api/records',
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': 'Secret'
    },
    params: {
    }
};

await axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
    //console.log(response.data);

    let i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        console.log(response.data[i].id);
    }        
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
}

function main() {
    console.log("Hi!");
    get_all_id();
}

main();
```

And here is the response in the console:

```
PS C:\Users\Enzo\Documents\dev\passerelle> node .\script.js
Hi!
PS C:\Users\Enzo\Documents\dev\passerelle>
```

I don't know how to stock and parse the "response.data" in an object and return it to the main function...

If someone can help me with that i will be very greatfull !

Comment: is it printing data in console.log when "console.log(response.data);"?

Comment: Yes like this
    `}, {'@id': ..., '@type': 'Record', id: '...', user: [Object], } ], 'hydra:totalItems': 836802, },`

Comment: for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        console.log(response.data[i]);
    }
---------
what coming in this?

Comment: Nothing, for him "response.data.length" is "undefined" when i just try this         "console.log(response.data.length);"

Comment: await axios(config)
.then(function (response.json()) {
    console.log(response.data);

Comment: try above snippet. Convert your response into json ans then try to print response and response length.

Comment: ok i do that `    await axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        response.data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        console.log(response.data.length); 
    })`  and i got the length

Comment: Length was undefined with your previous code.  So now you can iterate over it. Because you should convert response into json. Hope it helps.

Comment: I do that ,
`response.data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
            console.log(response.data[i]);
        } `
and i got all response.data[i] parsed one by one char ex:
response.data[0] = a
response.data[1] = p
response.data[2] = i
response.data[3] = /

it's to much, i just want all string to be parsed, not all char...

Comment: try to understand how to loop on json in js. this can help you in future also.

Comment: Yes I'm trying Thx for help